# Sage is unable to process .sagetex.sage file created from sagetex

Tags: pdftex, errors, compilation-error, python, sagetex

This is a simple `.tex` file that defines a sage function `p(n)` that returns 2 raised to the power of `n`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
def p(n):
    return 2**n
\end{sagesilent}

2 to the power of 50 equals $\sagestr{p(50)}$.

\end{document}
```

As expected the compiling the `.tex` file generates a `.sagetex.sage` file. However, When I run `sage test.sagetex.sage` on terminal I unexpectedly got an error message.

```
Processing Sage code for test.tex...
Code block (line 5) begin...end
Inline formula 0 (line 10)

**** Error in Sage code on line 10 of test.tex! Traceback follows.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.sagetex.sage.py", line 20, in <module>
    _st_.inline(_sage_const_0 , p(_sage_const_50 ))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sagetex.py", line 122, in inline
    '}{{%\n' + s.rstrip() + '}{}{}{}{}}\n')
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 493, in sage.structure.element.Element.__getattr__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4708)
    return self.getattr_from_category(name)
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 506, in sage.structure.element.Element.getattr_from_category (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4820)
    return getattr_from_other_class(self, cls, name)
  File "sage/cpython/getattr.pyx", line 372, in sage.cpython.getattr.getattr_from_other_class (build/cythonized/sage/cpython/getattr.c:2619)
    raise AttributeError(dummy_error_message)
AttributeError: 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

**** Running Sage on test.sage failed! Fix test.tex and try again.
```

Is there something wrong with my TeX code? Is this not the right order of compiling files? Is my sage installation corrupt?

Comment: Welcome! I know nothing of sage, but from the error seems that `sagestr` is expecting a string argument, and you are passing an integer one. This is more a python-sage problem than a LaTeX one...

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong function. According to the official SageTeX manual:

> **`\sage`**
>
> `\sage{<Sage code>}` takes whatever Sage code you give it, runs Sage’s latex
> function on it, and puts the result into your document.
>
> **`\sagestr`**
>
> `\sagestr{<Sage code>}` is identical to `\sage`, but is does ***not*** run Sage’s LaTeX
> function on the code you give it; it simply runs the Sage code and pulls the result
> into your LaTeX file. This is useful for calling functions that return LaTeX code;

Thus `\sage` is the right choice here. Simply replacing `\sagestr` with `\sage` does the job. Just compile your `.tex` file again afterwards to see the `??` replaced with `1125899906842624`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
def p(n):
    return 2**n
\end{sagesilent}

2 to the power of 50 equals $\sage{p(50)}$.

\end{document}
```